# Invalid credentials error for Cloudhub connector

Tags: anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I configured cloudhub connector using anypoint credentials to create notification for time out error. when I tried to test application, I am getting an error as

> Invalid Credentials" error type: CLOUDHUB-CONNECTIVITY

The below code is how I configured it in Mule 4. Is this related to permissions of my anypoint account?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I too was getting this issue and through trial and error it appears that the user raising the notification needs at minimum the 'Read Applications' permission on the environment in question.

In Mule 4 you can also optionally specify the environment id in the config; using the system property ${environment.id} if you want it to apply to the environment where your app is deployed, eg:

```
<cloudhub:config name="CloudHub_Config" doc:name="CloudHub Config">
  <cloudhub:connection username="${cloudhub.username}" password="${cloudhub.password}" environment="${environment.id}" />
</cloudhub:config>
```

If this is environment attribute is omitted, I believe it uses the one defined as default in Anypoint Platform.

Comment: Though I got this error in the console, It worked fine when I looked in the runtime manager for notification.